# Spring Batch as Tenant Initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In our projects we use **mulitenancy** and every tenant needs to be initialized when created.
Lets assume we have to import some data to database from different places (other db, files, events) then process the data and save in database, at the end publish state.

We collected requirements internally, and then figure out that all of them, and even more, are implemented as features in spring-batch - awesome!
What turned out later, is that spring batch perfectly supports chunking and partitioning within single job, but is not designed to run the same job in parallel.

Despite the fact, we decided to implement `tenant-init-job` that we will run with different `tenant` parameters, because the the sequence of steps is the same for all tenants, only parameters are different.

That works nice, if we have tenant-by-tenant initialization. But we wanted to extend this framework and implement parallel initalization, by running jobs in parallel for different tenants.

I faced some problems, that I dont know how to solve or overcome.
This is more like question to validate the idea - maybe I should not use spring batch in this way or mabye i miss important details.

1. Is the idea correct? Or it does not have any chances to succseed? Any hints or suggestions?
2. It is not possible to run the same job, so I have to create new job with different name (tenant name included) and run them. That is a bit workaround - it gives the impression we are running different jobs, but they are the same at the end. I dont like it as we have to create jobs manually, rather than inject, but ok. That will make a bit harder to collect metrics from all jobs, but still, it works!
3. I got many errors like this:

```
ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep:257   --- Encountered an error executing step link-x-to-y-step in job init-123456_7890
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:224)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:153)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:417)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:132)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:316)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:285)
    at io.micrometer.context.ContextSnapshot.lambda$wrap$0(ContextSnapshot.java:91)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream is already initialized.  Close before re-opening.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:427)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:149)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

with all those readers: Jpa/Jdbs Cursor/Paging -> later i found they inherit from `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` class that is not thread safe. So I decided to create new Reader for every job (did not test @StepScoped yet). The problem is it still fails with same error, less often, but error is there. When bigger (more than 5 threads) concurrency is used, the more errors we have. I cannot figure out why it happens if i have separated reader objects and they do not seem to share static context. Also, using `synchronized` reader would not help us - it would sync invocation between threads, but since i have completely separated objects, i dont have to do it. Could it be because of `volatile` fields used in `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` ?

4. I already use my custom `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` in `TaskExecutorJobLauncher` to make sure every job has separate thread. I also give a try to launch jobs from same executor (so job launching is not always in same thread) but without success. Tried new thread for every job as well, did not help at all.

What I really want to avoid is developing custom readers - that sounds like project itself.

Thanks